# How to trim substrings after a non-letter token in Java

Tags: regex, java-8, split, trim

I have a string. In my code, I'm trying to trim substrings after a non-letter token if there are any. What do you think would be a better way to do that?

I tried split, replaceAll functions and matches function with regex but couldn't deliver a good solution.

```
String initialString = "Brown 1fox jum'ps over 9 the_t la8zy dog.";
String[] splitString = initialString.split(" ");
String finalString= new String();   
for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length; i++) {
    finalString+=splitString[i].split("[^a-zA-Z]",2)[0]+" ";
}
finalString=finalString.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

**Actual Result** (as expected)**:** "Brown jum over the la dog"

Comment: "I tried split, replaceAll functions and matches function with regex but couldn't make it" **Show us**. Maybe you were close.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to split each element and check whether they include a part starting with a non-letter token and if so, remove it. But it seems inefficient to me. I'm working on it right now tho, in case nobody comes up with a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you might use [`[^a-zA-Z ]+\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/KDsfjy/1) 
 to replace the matches with an empty string and after that replace the double whitespace characters with a single using [`\\s{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/KDsfjy/2)

```
String string = "Brown 1fox jum'ps over 9 the_t la8zy dog.";
String result = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]+\\S*", "").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NSWP42260)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is this,

```
String initialString = "Brown 1fox jum'ps over 9 the_t la8zy dog.";
String resultStr = Stream.of(initialString.split(" "))
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z].*", ""))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: `initialString.split(" ")` return an `array`, so use `Arrays.stream(initialString.split(" "))` instead of `Stream.of`

Comment: it also seems that since jdk-11 we will be able to do : `Predicate.not(String::isEmpty)` instead of `s -> !s.isEmpty()`

Comment: @Eugene What is the gain we get by using `Arrays.stream` instead of `Stream.of`?